# why am i getting the following error "GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=ObFGEV1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" after deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, localhost

Here is my server.js code:

```
const __dirname1 = path.resolve();
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, '/frontend/build')));
  app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname1,"frontend","build","index.html"));
  })
}else{
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running");
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
  cors: {
    origin:
      "*",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("connected to socket.io");
  socket.on("setup", (userData) => {
    socket.join(userData._id);
    socket.emit("connected");
  });
});
```

Here is my frontend code where i am using the socket:

```
import { ChatState } from "../Context/ChatProvider";
const ENDPOINT = "https://wechatt-chatt-app.onrender.com";
var socket, selectedChatCompare;

const SingleChat = ({ fetchAgain, setFetchAgain }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit("setup", user);
    socket.on("connected", () => setSocketConnected(true));
    socket.on("typing", () => setIsTyping(true));
    socket.on("stop typing", () => setIsTyping(false));
  }, []);
```

the url of my site is "https://wechatt-chatt-app.onrender.com"
I have deployed it on render with npm backend/server.js as start command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.